# BufferedWriter is not writing data properly

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, filewriter, bufferedwriter

What is wrong in the below code? in console it is printing proper data but in file there is no data. it is creating 0-byte file.

```
 JsonObjectBuilder mainObj= Json.createObjectBuilder();
        mainObj.add("delete",delete);
        mainObj.add("update", update);
        mainObj.add("add",add);
       
        String data = mainObj.build().toString();
        System.out.println(data); **//This line printing output**
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:/test.json"));
        out.write(data);
```

Below output is getting printed to console but it is creating 0-byte file.

```
{"delete":[{"canonicalName":"Amazon"}],"update":[{"canonicalName":"Infosys"},{"canonicalName":"Google HYD"}],"add":[{"canonicalName":"Apple computers"},{"canonicalName":"Microsoft India"},{"canonicalName":"Amazon"},{"canonicalName":"Google India"},{"canonicalName":"CSC"},{"canonicalName":"INFY"}]}
```

Comment: Try calling `out.close()`, which will flush and close the underlying stream . See : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html

Comment: As @Arnaud says, you should `.close()` the `BufferedWriter`. In your case this is not only a side note for good practice, but actually the reason for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you forgot to close the writer.
Instead of out.close() you can also use the new syntax [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) since Java 7:

```
try (BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:/test.json"))) {
    out.write(data);
}
```

This will automatically close all Closeables at the end of the try block.
Attention: the FileWriter will not be closed by the try-with-resource mechanism as there is no variable created for the FileWriter. Luckily the BufferedWriter.close() will also close the passed FileWriter.